# Intercept and prevent command from running in bash

Tags: bash

Is it possible to intercept all commands in bash and the prevent some of the from executing? Like with 'trap' command, only disallow to execute the command further.

I'm a web developer and currently working on a small project/script that would help a web developer in daily life by adding different aliases dynamically. For instance, as a web developer, on Ubuntu one usually hosts all projects in /var/www/ structure, thus it is possible to alias those folders in that (/var/www) folder. I want to improve my script a bit and add aliases to projects depending on which framework they're built. If it's Magento 2, then by running setup:upgrade it should run "bin/magento setup:upgrade".
I've tried trap 'something' DEBUG, but it is not possible to prevent the previous command, as far as I know.
Thanks!

Comment: Instead of trying to intercept the command and cancel it, have you considered writing a script/function that examines at the current dir and executes a command accordingly?'

Comment: Initial plan was to fix typos, so it would extremely cool if the functions could be created dynamically, right in-time. This is the way I would go for if the intercepting is not possible. Thanks!

Comment: You can always override a command with a function or alias, and then choose (or not) to call the backing command

Comment: If you use Linux take a look at [SELinux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security-Enhanced_Linux).

Comment: @thatotherguy, is it possible to do it somehow automatically on the execution? If I wanted to intercept all commands, I'd have to alias all results of "compgen -acb" (kind of a lot, 3000+). I tried to do so by creating aliases in the trap I mentioned previously, but it seems that the OS already has in mind what it'll execute and the alias is not working from the first trap.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. `trap ... DEBUG` is a good start and if you want to prevent some commands, you must associate it with `shopt -s extdebug`. Then, if you return from the trap with a non-zero status, the command will not be executed.

```
$ trap 'if [[ "$BASH_COMMAND" == "echo "* ]]; then printf "[%s]\n" ${BASH_COMMAND#echo}; false; fi' DEBUG
$ set -T              # Necessary for subshells and functions
$ shopt -s extdebug
$ echo foo bar
[foo]
[bar]
$ trap - DEBUG
$ echo foo bar
foo bar
```

Comment: Exactly what I as looking for. This can override any builtin, alias or command, right? Thanks a lot for the shopt -t suggestion!

Comment: Glad it helped. It can override whatever the DEBUG `trap` traps. I don't know much about it. Aliases are expanded, so you won't see them. Unless you "`set -T`", commands inside functions and subshells won't be trapped, which is probably not what you want. I'll add this to my answer.

Answer (score 6):

You can veto commands by abusing `command_not_found_handle`:

```
# Save the PATH
realpath="$PATH"
# Set a PATH without commands (weirdly can't be empty)
PATH="/"

command_not_found_handle() (
  if [[ "$1" == *d* ]]
  then
    echo "Sorry, no commands with 'd' allowed" >&2
    return 1
  else
    PATH="$realpath" 
    unset command_not_found_handle
    "$@"
  fi
)
```

With this in your `.bashrc`, you can run `ls` and `chown` but not `find` or `chmod`. Note that it does not affect functions or builtins.

Comment: Clever. It's an important detail that you're running all this in a subshell, which is why the `unset` and `PATH` assignment don't break it going forward.